# UTF-8 encoding prefix notiation "percent(%)" vs "backslash(\)"

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8

I just wonder about prefix of UTF-8 code notation. In some cases, it is represented as `\uc774\ud2b8` using backslash symbol (\). However, I can also find codes using percent symbol (%). e.g. `%uc774%ud2b8`.
There is no problem with modern browsers whatever I use, but when I use percent notation, `NSURL` cannot recognize codes returning object containing null URL.

What is right notation of UTF-8 code, and how can I solve the problem when I use `NSURL` with percent prefixed url string?

**EDIT**: I was wrong to word `UTF-8`. It is correct to refer to `Unicode character set` rather than `UTF-8 encoding`.

Comment: So you are talking about encoding UTF-8 characters in a URL?

Comment: Not only for URL, but asking about difference between two prefix. In addition, since `NSURL` doesn't work with % notation, I wonder about the solution of the problem (in iOS).

Comment: OK therefore you are talking about how a specific language encodes UTF-8 characters in string literals.  So you need to be more specific about the language you are talking about, not the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with UTF-8. The `\u` notation is used by various languages (C, Java) to encode Unicode characters into strings. When the string `"\uc774\ud2b8"` is encountered, it'll generally be encoded in UTF-8, which means it's the byte sequence 0xEC 0x9D 0xB4 0xED 0x8A 0xB8. But it could be encoded other ways, such as 0xC774 0xD2B8 (UTF-16). It depends on your system. But the point is that this string is 2 unicode characters long.

The `%` encoding is completely different. It's the percent-encoding standard for URI reserved characters defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). When your compiler encounters `"%uc774%ud2b8"` it will encode it as "%" "u" "7" "7" "4", etc. (Typically it will encode each of these in UTF-8, but it depends on the system). Most languages do not treat `%` as special. `\u` (and `\` generally) is part of the language. `%` is not. So this string is 12 unicode characters long.  The language does not care about `%`. URL parsers do.

In order for iOS to convert a string to an `NSURL`, the string must be correctly encoded. That may include percent-encoding in some parts of the URL and may forbid percent-encoding in other parts of the URL (and which characters may or must be percent-encoded can be different in different parts of the URL). The rules are spelled out in RFC 3986.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by,

**Old mthod**

```
    NSString * newString = [myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //Deprecated now
```

myString is urlstring having percent and newString is your desired string.

**New Method:**

```
 NSString * newString = [myString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` or `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` returns `nil` for this string `[@"http://www.example.org/index.html?arg=%uc774%ud2b8" stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]`